# click button with jquery

Tags: jquery, button, click

im trying to click a button only using jquery.
Im passing the button i want to click through the URL like this 
           http:www.website.com/website/section#create_new

#create_new

is the id of the button i want to click.
then with jquery i have this code

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf('create_new') != -1){

    $('#create_new').click();
    console.log('button clicked');

}
```

but nothing happens.
the console log flag fires but the button click does not.
anyone knows how to fire a button click with jquery?

thank you so much

Comment: That should work unless `#create_new` doesn't exist at that moment. http://jsfiddle.net/Q82Rn/

Answer (score 2):

Programatically triggering a button click will run the defined click handler, **not** the native click functionality. If there is no handler defined, nothing will happen.

Comment: the best way i found is to use this jquery plug in https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eduardolundgren/jquery-simulate/master/jquery.simulate.js